# TypeORM does not respect UnionTypes in FindOneby function

Tags: node.js, typeorm

I have created a Union Type which looks like this

```ts
type Nullable<T> = T | null;
```

This type is used in my application and has also worked without problems so far, e.g. such a type is passed to a function here:

```ts
 static async UpdateImage(existingImage: Nullable<string>){}
```

But now it seems that since TypeORM version 0.3 my union types are ignored, this happens in the following code block:

```ts
const entityToUpdate: MenuRecord= await MenuRecord.findOneByOrFail({
                            Image: existingImage,
                            ID: mId,
                            Owner: Equal(user)
                        });
```

The error occurres at `Image: existingImage`.
Here is the error message:

```
TS2322: Type 'Nullable<string>' is not assignable to type 'string | FindOperator<string> | undefined'.   Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | FindOperator<string> | undefined'
```

It looks to me like TypeORM is ignoring the null from my union type here and only recognising the string type.

In the entity model, however, the property is also defined as a union:

```ts
    @Column({name: "assignedImage", type: "varchar", length: 32, nullable: true})
    Image: Nullable<string>
```

The assignment in FindOne would work as soon as I define my type as `string|undefined`, but that would mean that I would have to use `string|undefined` instead of `Nullable<string>`in my entire application and thus rewrite everything.

Is there another solution for this?

Comment: Can you redefine `type Nullable<T> = T | undefined`?  Does that work, or at least cut down on refactoring?  Do you use an IDE that allows for symbol renaming that works across project as that might save some refactoring effort.

Comment: Release notes for 0.3 state: "[null as value in where used in find* methods is not supported anymore. Now you must explicitly use IsNull() operator.
](https://typeorm.io/changelog#breaking-changes-1)".  The error you quote seems to be in the case that `null` is passed

Comment: In fact, that was the problem, I assigned zero directly as a value.
Thanks for clarifying!